# Describe Number Naturally

Tags: notation, calculator

I'm running some calculations on a calculator, and I'm getting a lot of "exponent of 10" results. I was hoping somebody could help me translate the results to a "normal" representation, so that I can better understand what is going on.

For example, 3.772819472616633e-4 would become, I imagine, something like 0.000000...? Am I mistaken?

I would like write each of the following numbers without the 'exponent of 10' notation, but I'm not sure how to do that.

3.772819472616633e-4
1.476959432847578e-4‬
2.434077079107505e-5

**P.S. If my tags are the wrong ones, please adjust them. Thanks.**

Comment: Some calculators let you specify fixed vs scientific notation, so you might be able for "force" the more familiar format.

Comment: @MPW yeah ive tried switching between modes in the window calculator, but no dice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat the $+$ or $-$ sign like the direction on the number line ($+$ is right and $-$ is left).

Move the decimal point the number of spaces in the direction indicated:

- $1.23\text{e-2} = 0.0123$
- $1.23\text{e+2} = 123$
- $1.234567\text{e+10} = 12345670000$
- $1.234567\text{e-10} = 0.0000000001234567$

Comment: ohhhh ok, so whereever the decimal is, it moves however many positions indicated by the `-n` or `+n`

Comment: That's correct. The reason, of course, is that $\text{e-n}$ is shorthand for $\times 10^{-n}$ and $\text{e+n}$ is shorthand for $\times 10^{+n}$. You multiply by $10^{+n}$ ($10^{-n}$) by moving the decimal right (left) $n$ places.

Comment: negative exponents is just as confusing to me as the exponent notation lol. anyways, really appreciate your help!!

Comment: Actually, "shorthand" is probably a poor term. Older calculators only had seven rectangular lights to render a number or letter, and "E" is a letter that could be rendered clearly with this kind of display.

Comment: P.S. a negative exponent $10^{-n}$ is, in a sense, just notation for $1/10^n$.

Answer (score 3):

The "e-4" you see just means $\times 10^{-4}$. Similarly a "e+4" would mean $\times 10^4$.

For example: $1.23 \text{e-4} = 0.000123$, and $1.23 \text{e+4} = 12300$.

Comment: so lets see if i understand this. `3.772819472616633e-4` would become `0.0003772819472616633` and `2.434077079107505e-5` would become `0.00002434077079107505`??

Comment: That's correct.